# what does "\" symbol mean?

Tags: database-theory

I am new to database learning and came across this `\` symbol. I googled but couldn't find what it meant.

It was used in the context `Q = R\S`, where Q, R, and S are relations.

(The = sign here means "is equivalent to").

Comment: Came across it where? And what did they say it meant there?

Answer (score 5):

The `\` symbol is often used in mathematics for [set difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28set_theory%29#Relative_complement), besides dash or minus symbol (`-`)

Since tables and relations are very similar to sets and the operations of union, intersection and difference are similarly defined (see Wikipedia: [Relational algebra, set operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Set_operators)), the `\` symbol is also sometimes used for difference.

If the `Q = R\S` expression is found in a database theory book and `Q`, `R` and `S` are relations, it means that `Q` is a relation (table) that has the same attributes (columns) as `R` and `S` and also has those tuples (rows) that are in relation `R` but not in relation `S`.